# Is it safe to use the bigalloc feature in the case of ext4 filesystem?

Tags: filesystems, ext4

In the man ext4(5) we can read the following:

> Warning: The bigalloc feature is still under development, and may not
> be fully supported with your kernel  or  may have various bugs.
> Please see the web page http://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Bigalloc
> for details.  May clash with delayed allocation (see nodelalloc mount
> option).

According to the link above, the info is dated back to 2013, which is a little bit ancient.

What's the current status of the feature? Is it safe to use `bigalloc` on several TiB hard disks where only big files will be stored?

Comment: Best to ask this directly on the linux-ext4@vger.kernel.org list, and update here once you get a response.

Comment: I'll try to do that.

Comment: I asked (https://marc.info/?l=linux-ext4&m=162705422926698&w=2), but I don't think that someone ever is going to respond to that message...

Answer (score 0):

There was actually still a bug with bigalloc until Kernel 4.20. If your kernel is not up-to-date you may experience this problem: [Bug 151491 - free space lossage on busy system with bigalloc enabled and 128KB cluster](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=151491):

> file system with bigalloc enabled and 128KB cluster size with a large
> number of 2MB files being created/overwritten/deleted loses usable
> space.
>
> Running du and df gives wildly different usage with df showing much
> more usage than du. lsof shows no phantom open files. Using dd to fill
> the file system shows that df's version of free space is operative,
> but unmounting and remounting the file system returns the free space.
> There is no difference between df and du usage after remount.
>
> The fault does not seem to be present in the 4.7 kernel (or it takes a
> lot more activity for it to show up).

However, I don't know if this is the only problem or if there are maybe others.